# front end automation javascript vs Java or Ruby

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver-io

I am looking for information on why using JS framework (such as `webdriverio`) is better for front end automation as oppose to using selenium with widely used languages such as Java or Ruby.

I know that `webdriverio` and JS takes an asynchronous approach to front end automation testing which may be beneficial for AJAX calls and APIs behind the front end. But I am looking for some specific examples  with code which shows that using Java is not recommended or is tedious as opposed to using JS. I tried to search but couldn't get a clear explanation where advantages of JS over Java is shown as far as front end automation is concerned unless there are none or minimal.

Comment: This question will likely get closed as off-topic (e.g. asking for recommendations).  That being said, what language is the application-under-test written in?  That can help inform your decision.

Comment: @ orde  I suspected that it may get closed but I could not find any concrete answer while searching. AUT is mainly JS on front end and Java on backend.

Comment: Frameworks like `webdriverio` and `nightwatchjs` sit on top of node.js.  There's also `phantomjs` for headless testing.  If it's the Java route, then `selenium` is an obvious choice.  Might need to work some a few tutorials to make the determination.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would always go with Java, C sharp or some other statically typed language when doing test automation.  The reason is the page object design pattern is arguably more suited to statically typed languages.

See this post for more details:
[Is JavaScript compatible with strict Page Object Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960059/is-javascript-compatible-with-strict-page-object-pattern)

Comment: thank you for the reply - I think if I understood correctly , your main concern is autocomplete. Does using `vim` or any such tool suffice that? My point is that just for autocompletion , can the benefits of javascript be ignored like - 1)using JS to find elements, wherever driver fell short (pop ups and alerts), 2) using `node.js` for large data driven (or DB driven) tests as `node.js` may optimize I/O operations. 3) option to write tests in asynchronous way , if one is comfortable. Just my thoughts