# Is JavaScript compatible with strict Page Object Pattern?

Tags: javascript, java, testing, ui-automation, pageobjects

I have built various Test Automation frameworks using the Page Object Pattern with Java (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects).

Two of the big benefits I have found are:

1) You can see what methods are available when you have an instance of a page (e.g. typing homepage. will show me all the actions/methods you can call from the homepage)

2) Because navigation methods (e.g. goToHomepage()) return an instance of the subsequent page (e.g. homepage), you can navigate through your tests simply by writing the code and seeing where it takes you.

e.g.

```
WelcomePage welcomePage = loginPage.loginWithValidUser(validUser);
PaymentsPage paymentsPage = welcomePage.goToPaymentsPage();
```

These benefits work perfectly with Java since the type of object (or page in this case) is known by the IDE.

However, with JavaScript (dynamically typed language), the object type is not fixed at any point and is often ambiguous to the IDE. Therefore, I cannot see how you can realise these benefits on an automation suite built using JavaScript (e.g. by using Cucumber).

Can anyone show me how you would use JavaScript with the Page Object Pattern to gain these benefits?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this pattern, but the question itself feels like it may be too broad for this site... Some JS IDEs are pretty good at picking up on what properties an object should have. Also, Typescript could be an option if you don't mind the extra compiling step.

Comment: are you asking this question for all languages :) ?

Comment: Nah... just javascript and ruby :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not much about this patterns.but i will give some details maybe it helps to you.
http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

http://www.assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/

It seems a great way to achieve this is to use `TypeScript` (which is a statically typed version of `JavaScript`):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript

Answer (score 3):

From Gerrit0's comment above and investigating it further, it seems a great way to achieve this is to use TypeScript (which is a statically typed version of JavaScript):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript

Comment: Just be aware that Typescript has to compile down to javascript and javascript is loosely typed. Typescript gives compile-time feedback, but has no runtime guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jetbrains products like IntelliJ IDEA it will do a code completion and ther proper navigation for you. In javascript world page object is a known pattern too. AngularJs offers it too in it's own e2e test framework (http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects). Personally I use IIFE for page objects and IntelliJ does the rest. If it doesn't fit to your needs you can still choose typescript and transpile it to javascript.

Comment: IntelliJ is for Java.  I used Jetbrains IDEA for javascript (called WebStorm) but this did not work I'm afraid since the page object types are not known.